# Any reception reports from ExseedSAT1 yet?

Tags: satellites

My answer to the question [Where can I find the TLE of ExseedSat 1, India's first ever private LEO satellite?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33031/12102) is currently that while 60+ objects are being tracked from this mutli-payload launch, ExseedSat has not yet been unambiguously identified, so it's impossible to know which TLE would belong to that satellite.

According to the [ExseedSat1 webpage](https://www.exseedspace.com/exseed-sat-1)

> As it orbits around the earth, every minute it will whistle out the letter ‘V’ in Morse code (remember Beethoven’s 5th symphony? Yes, those notes).
>
> This will be followed by telemetry in radio teletype format. Watch a simulated test: https://youtu.be/da0y_InGffY

**NOTE:** if you watch the video, skip ahead to `05:14` or 1h 45m 15s on the display in the video to see the tape-measure antenna unwind and the satellite send it's "V".

The page goes on to identify the various teams involved, and many of the leads have callsigns.

I can keep an eye on the satcat report, but I don't know where to look to find out if there have been any reports of receiving any signal from this satellite? Is there a good place to watch for one?

Comment: If anyone knows of an unofficial TLE for Exseedsat-1 please feel free to add a new answer directly to the [linked question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33031/12102).